Manually update 3D Object pivot point in three JS
I'm quite new to ThreeJS and I just got this car model on Sketchfab, but when i try to put it in my React Three Fiber app it display very far away in the scene, when I attempt to rotating it follow the Y axis cause the object float around instead rotating around the axis. I put it in Threejs Editor and turn out the pivot point is outside the car instead in the middle of the model.

So my question is how can i update this pivot point with threejs code? Thanks in advance

Basically this is common issue, any chance to make Sandbox or code?
